# Can't use Symfony Mailer to send a templated email anymore?

Tags: php, symfony, email, smtp

I am trying to send templated emails, everything works fine with just text or html, but when I try to use TemplatedEmail instead of Email, I get this error: "A message must have a text or an HTML part or attachments.", as if I am not providing the htmlTemplate.

Here is the setup

```
$mailer = new Mailer(Transport::fromDsn($_ENV['SMTP_DNS']));

$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address('my_address', 'NAME'))
            ->to($userEmail)
            ->subject('Some text...')
            ->htmlTemplate('user/email.html.twig');

$mailer->send($email);
```

The twig is there, written correctly, I checked 100 times.

In twig.yaml, the path is also set corectly

```
twig:
    default_path: '%kernel.project_dir%/templates'
```

The twig itself just has a `<h1>Some text</h1>` tag, for testing, nothing more

I tried injecting the mailer directly in the controller (basically how it should be), but even tho the 'MAILER_DSN' is configured correctly, no email is sent.

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected, if you instantiate your Mail yourselves and you want the Twig integration, you need to wire it up as well.

The Mailer component has a MessageListener which is responsible for calling the BodyRenderer. But here, I created my own Mailer without injecting an EventDispatcher in it (so no events will be dispatched) and without configuring a MessageListener in this event dispatcher.

If you are using the Symfony framework, use the mailer service configured by FrameworkBundle (which already wires the MessageListener) rather than doing the instantiation yourselves, OR wire up the Twig integration.

To do that, you need to load the templates directory, and create a environment from it, and afterwards render it.

Here is the code for that:

```
$loader = new FilesystemLoader('Directory_name aka templates', 'App root aka /app');
$twigEnv = new Environment($loader);
$twigBodyRenderer = new BodyRenderer($twigEnv);
$twigBodyRenderer->render($email);
```

This did the trick for me, but again, use the mailer service configured by FrameworkBundle, it's much easier.

Final code (hard way):

```
$mailer = new Mailer(Transport::fromDsn($_ENV['SMTP_DNS']));

$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address('my_address', 'NAME'))
            ->to($userEmail)
            ->subject('Some text...')
            ->htmlTemplate('user/email.html.twig');

$loader = new FilesystemLoader('Directory_name aka templates', 'App root aka /app');
$twigEnv = new Environment($loader);
$twigBodyRenderer = new BodyRenderer($twigEnv);
$twigBodyRenderer->render($email);

$mailer->send($email);
```

Final code (normal way):

```
//inject MailerInterface $mailer

$email = (new TemplatedEmail())
            ->from(new Address('my_address', 'NAME'))
            ->to($userEmail)
            ->subject('Some text...')
            ->htmlTemplate('user/email.html.twig');

$mailer->send($email);
```

Hope this helps:)))